# How can I convert this list of numbers and symbols into a string?

Tags: string, scheme, racket

is there a way too convert a list like this into a normal string?
list->string does not work because it isn't a list of chars.
It is a bit problematic because the list consists of symbols and numbers :/

`(list + 4 * 5 - 3 6)         //-> "+4*5-36"`

Answer (score 2):

**Standard Scheme**

For numbers:

```
(number->string 123 10) ; ==> "123"
```

For symbols:

```
(symbol->string 'test) ; ==> "test"
```

So you can check what type it is and use the correct procedure to convert to string. You can use `string-append` so join more strings together.

```
(string-append (symbol->string '+)
               (number->string 4)
               (symbol->string '*)
               (number->string 5)
               (symbol->string '-)
               (number->string 3)
               (number->string 6))
; ==> "+4*5-36"
```

If you make a procedure `any->string` you can make a one level list to string like this with SRFI-1:

```
(foldr (lambda (e a) (string-append (any->string e) a))
       ""
       '(+ 4 * 5 - 3 6))
; ==> "+4*5-36"
```

**Racket**

Racket has `format`. If you do `(format "~a" data)` it will produce a string:

```
(format "~a" '(+ 4 * 5 - 3 6))
; ==> "(+ 4 * 5 - 3 6)"
```

Note that the first element of `(list + 4 * 5 - 3 6)` isn't the symbol `+` since the **variable** `+` gets evaluated to a procedure that adds stuff. eg. `(+ 3 4) ; ==> 7` and `+ ; ==> #<procedure:+>` (in racket; implementation specific)

Answer (score 0):

I will show you in *mit-scheme*:

```
(define input '(+ 4 * 5 - 3 6))

(fold-right (lambda (x acc)
              (string-append ((cond ((number? x) number->string )
                                    ((symbol? x) symbol->string ))
                                    (else (error "unknown case" x))
                              x)
                             acc))
            ""
            input)
```

Example:

```
1 ]=>
(define input '(+ 4 * 5 - 3 6))
;Value: input
...
;Value: "+4*5-36"
```

In case the list contains more kind of symbolic expressions, apart from numbers and symbols, you extend the `cond-statement` with other cases.

Also, do not forget to quote the input, otherwise `+` gets evaluated to a strange value.